# Visual Studio Preview for Mac 2017 .NET Core build error

Tags: macos, visual-studio, .net-core

When I try to run the .NET Core Project on last version of Visual Studio Preview for Mac, I get next error:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.1' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
  1.1.0
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.1'.
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGQUIT

WARNING: The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.0 or newer. This may be expected if the target process did not run .NET code.
```

I opened Project Settings, and in the 'Target Framework' Dropdown there is no .NETCoreApp 1.1, only 1.0 (which is not installed)

What should I change in project or Studio configs for project to run successfully? Or I just must wait for VS update?
Thanks for response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Step 1:** setup `.net Core`

  --> https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

  --> if you get `donet new` command not found, try this: `ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/`
- **Step 2:** update packages

[image: update packages]

Answer (score 5):

Update your nuget packages i.e Project -> Update Nuget Packages. The Microsoft.NetCore.App package is out of date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it seems like there is no project.json file in my project hierarchy, or I don't know where it is located

Comment: I found `project.assets.json` file in the `obj` directory of my project. It's really big. But it's not showed in VS directly.

Comment: I assumed you meant Visual Studio Code. You should have a project.json in the root of your project. You can simply use Finder to get there. The project settings you are referring to may very well just be looking at the project.json file.

Comment: Okay so Visual Studio for Mac is a completely different beast. I had heard that they were going to do away with the problematic project.json and while you'll still get one if you use dotnet new from the command line, it's not present in a Visual Studio for Mac project (or at least the console app I created). I updated my answer.

Comment: When I do this on a brand new empty ASP.NET Core app I get nuget errors.  Looks like it has problems trying to load one of the dependencies via nuget.  Completely buggy experience thus far.  Can't even get an empty hello world project to compile and run... SMH

Comment: But! even after doing that, its still showing the (Not Installed) in the Target Framework selection.